# Attribute not found in module but it exists

Tags: python, module, attributes

When I run network.Network() I get an error that says **AttributeError: module 'network' has no attribute 'Network'**

I've used print(dir(network)) to get all the attributes and it shows. There's no spelling error in the code. I've copied and pasted both the network and Network names. I'm at a loss on what I can do.

I'm using pydroid.

network.py

```
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
        self.port = 1221
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.id = self.connect()

    def getPos(self):
        return self.id
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass
    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

game.py

```
import pygame
import network
dir(network)
clientNumber = 0
class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def updateTouch(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def read(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])

def make(tup):
    return str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1])

def redrawWindow(win, player, player2):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player2.draw(win)
    player.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.flip()
 
def main():
    
 running = True
 n = network.Network()
 startPos = read(n.getPos())
 AttackOne = Player(startPos[0], startPos[1], 100, 100, (0,255,0))
 AttackTwo = Player(0, 0, 100, 100, (255,0,0))
 pygame.init()
 pygame.font.init()
    
 
 while running:
  AttackTwoPos = read(n.send(make((AttackOne.x, AttackOne.y))))
  AttackTwo.x = AttackTwoPos[0]
  AttackTwo.y = AttackTwoPos[1]
  AttackTwo.update()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    AttackOne.updateTouch(x - 50, y - 50)
    
    print(x, y)

  
  
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    running = False
    pygame.quit()
    
  redrawWindow(screen, AttackOne, AttackTwo)    
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 45, in main
    n = network.Network()
AttributeError: module 'network' has no attribute 'Network'
```

Comment: Show us the full code that has the `network.Network()` call.  Also show us the full error traceback message.

Comment: I updated the post to include everything you asked for

Comment: Such an error should not be possible with this code.  Your actual code must be different than you have shown here.  (For example, your post says that the second code file is named `game.py`, but the actual error message refers to `temp_iiec_codefile.py`...)

Comment: Maybe you edited the file but forgot to save it in your editor, or maybe pydroid has some odd deployment scheme that requires extra steps to copy files around, or any of a hundred other possible problems that we can't possibly answer because we are not familiar with your local environment.

Comment: I see, I'm using termux also and downloaded the code from my Gmail. Somewhere the file must have been renamed in some metadata I can't see. I can confirm these are the exact file names and code I have. I will try making a new file and uploading the code into the new file.

Comment: I made a new file and renamed it. Funny enough it wasn't the network.py file having the issue, it was game.py.